# MySQL database not writing

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am using Spring to create a Java Service that is hosted through Tomcat locally. The user is able to store information from the service to a MySQL database. But when I try to create an entry, it gives me just hangs here. Here is the stack trace:

```
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for "http://localhost:8080/javaservice/admin/createinfo"
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [com.project1.set.transfer.infoTO@5d31159f] using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@590e9ae1]
```

Its just stuck in that Writing line. In the web browser it says "waiting for localhost". I have the schema created in MySQL and the MySQL database is running. Can someone help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Provide the code that implements your RESTful service. Probably there's an error like an infinite loop there or your table in mysql is locked.

Comment: I think the issue is the mysql. I am new to mysql and not sure much about it. Right now, I only have the schema made. Do I also need to create a table? What info in the table should match to the Server? I have a simple java object for the information submitted. For example, I have an Object Info that has 4 variables and filled out through user input. Does the table need to match those variables?

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is a class provided by spring used to map json objects into pojo's (plain old java objects). This issue does not sound like it is related to your database.

Either you are missing some dependencies or configuration for jackson, or something in your code is getting stuck prior to persisting the data to the database. Try using your IDE to step-by-step debug through the code as it runs, you may have an infinite loop.

Comment: It also says: DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'projectWebController'
null

Comment: I thought it might be a sql issue?

Comment: It is definitely an issue related to configuration of your MVC controller, not the database. Here is a nice tutorial that uses jackson to map. http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/. Once you get that working, look for tutorials on Hibernate or Spring-ORM for how to do database mapping.